# Tried to boot to safe mode through msconfig but laptop takes forever to reboot?

Tags: boot, reboot, safe-mode

I was trying to boot to safe mode through msconfig but after it restarts, it got stuck and it was all black. I tried to wait for it to boot but time has passed and it's still stuck.I am in Windows 10 from Windows 8.1 upgrade.

Comment: Have you tried powering off and then using F8 to boot into safe mode?

Comment: Yes, but after my laptop manufacturer logo appears, that's when it gets stuck.